# Creating locally database (SQL Server) from remote server for locally test environment

Tags: sql-server

I have to create script which will create the database locally (from database which is on server). Database is 20GB+ and every day is bigger.
What is your advise to do that? I can generate script with all database objects in SSMS, but how operate with data insertion? I mean full script (script which includes data) is not good option. What about one Full Backup and Differetial Backups?

1. Run generated scripts for all DB objects
2. Restore Full Backup
3. Restore Differential Backup

This work is required in order to make possible to test the app locally, on my (another dev's) machine. Thank for every advise!

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you running locally?

Comment: Standard Edition, but I'm working on selecting only needed data from DB (then it would be less then 10GB)

Comment: If you want to limit the data in the local copy then you'd need to script the insert/update/delete/merge statements.  Schema changes can be a real pain here.  There are [tools that can help with this](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/).  Backup/restore is faster, but you'll lose control over which records exist in the local db, unless you write a delete script to run after.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to go with a full backup first & get differential backups afterward.

Because a differential backup is not independent and it must be based on the latest full backup of the data. That means there should have a full backup as a base. A differential backup contains only the data that has changed since the differential base. Typically, differential backups are smaller and faster to create than the base of a full backup and also require less disk space to store backup images.

Therefore, using differential backups can save available space and also speed up the process of restoring. At restore time, the full backup is restored first, followed by the most recent differential backup.